# Data from mongodb does not display on react page

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

I'm working on a MERN application, with routings. My data will not display on my react page - here is my code

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

//Static images for page design
import update from './images/update.png';
import del from './images/del.png';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function ProductCatalog() {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([{}])
    let index= 0;
     useEffect(() => {
         Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getProducts').then((response) => {
             setProducts(response.data)
         })
       }, [])
    

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    function addProduct() {
            navigate('/adding')
     }
     function deleteProduct(id){
        Axios.delete(`delete/${id}`)
        navigate('/delete')
     }
     function updateProduct(Product){
        let Name = prompt("Please enter updated product name, or press OK:",Product.Name);
        let Description = prompt("Please enter udated description:",Product.Description);
        let Price = prompt("Please enter updated price:",Product.Price);
        let Stock = prompt("Please enter updated stock quantity:",Product.stock);
        let selectedImage = prompt("Please enter updated image address:",Product.selectedImage);

        axios.put('/update/'+Product._id, {
            Name,
            Description,
            Price,
            Stock,
            selectedImage
        })

        navigate('/updated')
     }
    
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <button className="button" data-testid="addnewpage" onClick={addProduct}>Add New Product</button>
                    <br></br>
                    
                    <div className="row">
                    {products.map((Product)=>{
                        let i = index;
                    index++;
                    return (
                            <div data-testid="renderProductList" className="before-footer-section product-section untree_co-section">
                                <div className="container">
                                        <div className="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-4 mb-5">
                                            <a className="product-item" href="#">
                                            <img src={Product.selectedImage} className="img-fluid product-thumbnail"/>
                                            <h3 className="product-title">{Product.Name}</h3>
                                            <strong className="product-price">{Product.Price}</strong>
                                            <p>{Product.Description}</p>
                            
                                            <span className="icon-cross" onClick={() => updateProduct(Product)}>
                                                <img src={update} className="img-fluid"/>
                                            </span>
                        
                                            <span className="icon-del" onClick={() => deleteProduct(Product._id)}>
                                                <img src={del} className="img-fluid"/>
                                            </span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div> 
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                      );
                })}
                </div>
        </React.Fragment>
        )
}
```

Upon clicking http://localhost:3001/getProducts, I see the data in raw format, but it will not display on this specific page. I used useEffect to set the data and mapped it in the return section.
Have I done something wrong?

Edited to add sample data:

```
[
{
"_id": "63529c01e89851e73debb467",
"Name": "Grey Swing Chair",
"url": "grey-swing-chair",
"Category": "Chairs",
"Price": 501,
"stock": 10,
"Description": "Something designed to support a person in a sitting position, as a chair, bench, or pew; a place on or in which one sits",
"selectedImage": "/images/product1.png",
"__v": 0
}
]
```

Comment: can you share a part of your data ? your code seems correct

Comment: @Neo, I edited to add a sample one from http://localhost/3001/getProducts

Comment: sorry but your code works fine in my browser